# Customize Error message for when ClickOnce application notices wrong version of .Net installed

Tags: c#, clickonce, custom-errors

When you try and run a .Net 4 ClickOnce application on a machine running .Net 3.5, it pops up the following error:

```
Unable to install or run this application. This application requires your system
to be updated to Microsoft Common Language Runtime Version 4.0.30319.0.

Please contact your system administrator.
```

My question is, is there any way to customize the body of this error message, so that I could put in a custom phone number to call, instead of displaying the above?

Note: I can't just include the prerequesites for the user to install, because the user does not have sufficient rights to install it by themselves anyways, hence why I want to add a phone number to our tech support staff in the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's think about this: the manifest file launches the deploy file launches the executable, I think the error message is coming from the deploy file as the executable cannot run without the proper framework.  Thereby the answer to your question would be no in a traditional sense.

Of course, you can use an existing app or service to customize that kind of error message, but you'd be stuck deploying that system as well.  What I don't get is my clickonce apps install the framework for you resolving the problem themselves, if yours don't for some reason, I'd recommend putting an executable of .NET 4 FW on a share and linking people from there.

Another hackish way you can do it, is if your setup is like mine, you have a web page that clickonce installs off, maybe you could check in that web page? You'd have to change from .htm to .aspx, but that's not a problem on an iis server.

Answer (score 0):

Is this an exception you can `catch` in code?  If so, you can just create and throw an exception with your own message.

```
throw new Exception("your message here");
```

Comment: I don't think so, as I have never seen an exception pop up a MessageBox without any extra code built in. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the value of `Environment.Version` on your initialization sequence to see what version of .NET is installed on the system, then display a message accordingly.